# Удаление всех символов переноса строки в файлах

Tags: powershell

Задача: Сделать скрипт, который будет удалять комментарии, табуляции и переносы строк во всех фалах в папке и вложенных папках.

Написал данный скрипт, он удаляет однострочные комментарии, табуляции и пробелы.

```
gci html/* -Include html,styles,*.*html,*.css | % {
    (Get-Content $_ | % {$_ -replace "//.*$" -replace "\s"}) | Set-Content $_ }
```

Необходимо добавить удаление символов переноса каретки в начало строки(\r,0x0D) и перехода на новую строку(\n,0x0A). И убрать удаление пробелов или отдельно сделать удаление табуляций(символ \s удаляет все без разбору).

Такие символы как: `n,`r,`t,\n,\r,\t команда упорно игнорирует. Пробовал передавать в -replace "\z", "$", "^" и сочетания этих символов, также пытался использовать функцию trim

`? {$_.trim('\r\n')}` тоже не выходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что Get-Content без флага -Raw преобразует полученные данные из файла в массив строк с делителем '\n'. Т.е. получал массив строк, а не файл целиком. А потом вставлял эти строки с помощью Set-Content с переходом на новую строку.

```
    try{
    gci html/* -Include html,styles,*.*html,*.css | % {
        (Get-Content $_ -Raw | % {$_ -replace "\s//.*`r`n" -replace "`r`n" -replace "`t"}) | Set-Content $_   
    }
} catch {
 Write-Host "ASHIBKA:"
  Write-Host $error[0]
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
}
```